# No application exists at /Today-View

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-app-extension

After a restart of Xcode I'm getting this message as I try to launch my today extension in iOS 8. Has anyone else this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be solved by making sure that `Debug Extensions and XPC services` in the Scheme is checked. Also make sure that Executable is not set to None.

[image: Debug Extensions and XPC services]

Comment: If the `Extensions and XPC services` is gray, try select valid target.